# How to put a function in a text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

How to put this method

```
    void fontControl() {
    setState(() {
      TextStyle(fontSize: 10 + count.toDouble());

      if (count == 100) {
        const TextStyle(fontSize: 100);
      }
    });
  }
```

to the text widget

```
Text(count.toString(), style: fontControl())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use method to provide style. For this you need to return `TextStyle`, therefore it cannot be void. Also, you can choose textStyle variable.

You can make it dynamic or better nullable return type. And use `SetState` on button click

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestS extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? name;
  const TestS({
    Key? key,
    this.name,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestS> createState() => _TestSState();
}

class _TestSState extends State<TestS> {
  int count = 0;

  TextStyle? fontControl() {
    if (count == 1) {
      return TextStyle(fontSize: 100);
    }
    return TextStyle(fontSize: 10 + count.toDouble()); //default
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        count++;
        setState(() {});
      }),
      body: Text(
        widget.name ?? "default value",
        style: fontControl(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that. What you can do is having a private mutable property name `_textStyle` that should change each time the `count` variable change.

If I take the flutter counter app example, you will have something like that

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  late TextStyle _textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0 + _counter);

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
      if (_counter > 100) {
        _textStyle = const TextStyle(fontSize: 100);
      } else {
        _textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0 + _counter);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: _textStyle,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in a GestureDetector widget with a GestureDetector.onTap handler :

```
onTap: (){
         // your function here
        },
```